# Regex - Replace is too slow

Tags: regex, rss, feed, xmlreader, rss-reader

On my Rss Feeds reading system I need to remove any existent script block because some people say this confuse XmlReader.

For that I'm doing this piece of code that I found on web:

```
allXml = Regex.Replace(allXml, "(.*)<script type='text/javascript'>.+?</script>(.*)", "$1$2");
```

But this is too slow... There is any way to perform this? I already tried to do the Match first but this is equally slow, like this:

```
Match rgx = Regex.Match(allXml, "(.*)<script type='text/javascript'>.+?</script>(.*)");

if (rgx.Success)
    allXml = Regex.Replace(allXml,"(.*)<script type='text/javascript'>.+?</script>(.*)","$1$2");
```

Comment: What's the size of `allXml`?

Comment: And this is working correctly, you have nowhere `type="text/javascript"` (double quotes)? Or whitespaces.

Comment: Try to understand what code you picked up from **web**. What it actually does. That way you will have clarity on what you are actually doing.

Here you are looking for `(everything)Javascript(everything)` ofcourse it will take time given the nature of Regular Expression's searching technique.

Comment: I suggest you search for script block and replace it with something which won't affect your code. Such as a blank comment or a newline.

Comment: The first `(.*)` is the culprit, use `Regex.Replace(allXml, "(?s)<script type='text/javascript'>.*?</script>", "")`. But the best way is to use the HTML parser, like HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does `(.*)` exactally? @ThomasAyoub, @maraca, @Rahul I never know what is the size of my `allXml` string and I never can know what html struture it can have because it is executed for different clients with differents feeds URLs which often change.

Comment: @Ninita First, the (.) matches everything, and the (\*) says it occurs 0 or more times for it to match. So what (.*) is saying, is that anything can match 0 or more times. Using the (.)* is terrible for performance and not terribly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `(.*)` grabs the whole line at once (since `*` is a greedy quantifier), and then starts backtracking trying to accommodate all the subsequent patterns. If your string is a very long line, several megabytes long, it might be problematic for the engine, as it will have to perform a lot of steps before it finds the appropriate string chunks for each capturing group defined in the pattern.

If you want a regex quick and dirty fix, discard the `(.*)`s, and just use

```
string res = Regex.Replace(allXml, "(?s)<script type='text/javascript'>.*?</script>", "")
```

to remove the `<script>...</script>` substrings. Note the `(?s)` is the `RegexOptions.Singleline` (DOTALL) modifier inline equivalent, so that `.` could match newline symbols, too.

However, the best way is to use an HTML parser, like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).